# Functional composition of different types of Tasks - Scala

Tags: scala, function-composition

Currently, I am working on a design to build a generic pipeline in Scala (purely for learning purposes). For this, I started with a basic construct, Task which takes some TaskConfiguration (for now, we can assume that this TaskConfiguration is a case class which is specific to the Task functionality). Trait structure is as follows:

```
trait Task[T <: TaskConfiguration] {
  type Out

  def taskConfiguration: T
  def execute(previousOutput: Option[Out]): Option[Out]
}
```

Requirements:
1. I could have multiple Tasks which are extending Task trait. Like, ReadTask, WriteTask, etc.,
2. Every task will have it's own type for "out"

My question is: Given a List[Task], how could I compose the method calls to execute. Tried multiple ways to compose them but I keep getting issue where I could not distinguish between previous task's out with the current task's out, given I have only one type member to specify what this task could handle.

I hope we could solve this with Scala. But given the fact that, I am pretty new to Functional Programming with Scala, I couldn't figure it out. Thank you very much in advance.

**Note**: Description to this question might seem a bit out of context. But this is the best I could come up with, at this point of time. Feel free to edit this, if you think we could make it better. If you think this question doesn't make any sense, please mention it in the comments with your thoughts, so that I could take care of it.

Comment: WDYM by "Compose the method calls to execute"?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Here we are dealing with List[Task] and need to invoke execute method on each Task, sequentially. It's like Task1's output should be input to Task2 and so on. For example, if the pipeline is like copying a file then the corresponding tasks would be ReadTask, WriteTask. ReadTask will read data from file and feeds the lines to WriteTask, which in turn writes to a different file. Please let me know if you need additional details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pattern similarly to `andThen` from Scala's functions.

I compiled a little example:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

type TaskConfiguration = Any

trait Task[-C <: TaskConfiguration, +O <: TaskConfiguration] {

  def execute(configuration: C): Option[O]

  def andThen[O2 <: TaskConfiguration](secondTask: Task[O, O2]): Task[C, O2] = {
    val firstTask = this

    new Task[C, O2] {
       def execute(configuration: C): Option[O2] =
         firstTask.execute(configuration).flatMap(secondTask.execute(_))
    }
  }
}

// From here on it's the example!

case class UnparsedNumber(value: String)

trait ParsedNumber {
  val value: Int
}

case class ParsedPositiveNumber(int: Int) extends ParsedNumber {
  val value: Int = int
}

case class HumanReadableNumber(value: String)


val task1 = new Task[UnparsedNumber, ParsedPositiveNumber] {
  def execute(configuration: UnparsedNumber): Option[ParsedPositiveNumber] = {
    Try(configuration.value.toInt) match {
      case Success(i) if i >= 0 => Some(ParsedPositiveNumber(i))
      case Success(_) => None
      case Failure(_) => None
    }
  }
}

val task2 = new Task[ParsedNumber, HumanReadableNumber] {
  def execute(configuration: ParsedNumber): Option[HumanReadableNumber] = {
    if(configuration.value < 1000 && configuration.value > -1000)
      Some(HumanReadableNumber(s"The number is $configuration"))
    else
      None
  }
}

val combined = task1.andThen(task2)

println(combined.execute(UnparsedNumber("12")))
println(combined.execute(UnparsedNumber("12x")))
println(combined.execute(UnparsedNumber("-12")))
println(combined.execute(UnparsedNumber("10000")))
println(combined.execute(UnparsedNumber("-10000")))
```

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/lwkSNEc/6)

---

**Edit:**

Regarding your comments, this approach might be more what you're looking for:

```
case class Task[-C, +O](f: C => Option[O]) {

  def execute(c: C): Option[O] = f.apply(c)
}

case class TaskChain[C, O <: C](tasks: List[Task[C, O]]) {

  def run(initial: C): Option[O] = {

    def runTasks(output: Option[C], tail: List[Task[C, O]]): Option[O] = {
      output match {
        case Some(o) => tail match {
          case head :: Nil => head.execute(o)
          case head :: tail => runTasks(head.execute(o), tail)
          case Nil => ??? // This should never happen!
        }
        case None => None
      }
    }

    runTasks(Some(initial), tasks)
  }
}

// Example below:

val t1: Task[Int, Int] = Task(i => Some(i * 2))
val t2: Task[Int, Int] = Task(i => Some(i - 100))
val t3: Task[Int, Int] = Task(i => if(i > 0) Some(i) else None)


val chain: TaskChain[Int, Int] = TaskChain(List(t1, t2, t3))

println(chain.run(100))
println(chain.run(10))
```

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/lwkSNEc/8)

Quote:

What you need to understand is that if you pack your `Task`s in a `List[Task]` and use it as a chain of `Task`s, the output has to be at least a subtype of the input. `C <: TaskConfiguration` and `O <: C` leads to: `O <: C <: TaskConfiguration` which also means `O <: TaskConfiguration`.

---

If you don't understand any part of this I will be happy to further explain.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Seems, my requirement is a bit different. "O" is not a sub type of TaskConfiguration. This should be a type member (which needs to be overridden by sub classes of Trait) and represents output of "execute" method. And "execute" takes previous "Task's execute method's output" as input. Please refer to my comment, in response to Yuval's question. Please correct me if went wrong.

Comment: @Krishna Look, what you need to understand is that if you pack your `Task`s in a `List[Task]` and use it as a chain of `Task`s, the output **has to be** at least a subtype of the input. `C <: TaskConfiguration` and `O <: C` leads to: `O <: C <: TaskConfiguration` which also means `O <: TaskConfiguration`.

Comment: @Krishna Take a look at this example: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/lwkSNEc/8

Comment: Changed my trait as per above comment and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Krishna happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look about what [cats and free monads](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/freemonad.html) can offer to you. Following that approach, I would start defining an ADT for defining pipeline programs. Something like :

```
trait TaskE[Effect]
case class ReadTask[Input, SourceConfig](source: SourceConfig) extends TaskE[Input]
case class WriteTask[Output, SinkConfig](out: Output, sink: SinkConfig) extends TaskE[Unit]
```

And then apply Free monads (as mentioned in above link) for defining your pipeline flow. Something like:

```
val pipeline: Task[Unit] = 
  for {
    input1 <- read(source1)
    input2 <- read(source2)
    _      <- write(input1 + input2, sink1)
  } yield ()
```

Now it will depend on the compiler (it's a natural transformation that describes how to convert from `Task[A]` to `F[A]`, and `F` may be `Id`,`Try`, `Future`, ...) you define how this program will run:

```
val myCompiler: Task ~> Id = ???
val tryCompiler: Task ~> Try = ???

pipeline.foldMap(myCompiler)  // Id[Unit]
pipeline.foldMap(tryCompiler) // Try[Unit]
```

You could have as many 'compilers' as you want and that doesn't imply changing your pipeline ('program') definition.

Comment: @Santos free monads seems to be an interesting concept. However, your reply is not addressing the composition part. In the given context, we will have a List[Task] that needs to be composed unlike the Pipeline example where I have a prior knowledge of how many tasks exists and their order of execution.